# Using xlsxwriter (or other packages) to create Excel tabs with specific naming, and write dataframe to the corresponding tab

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am trying to query based on different criteria, and then create individual tabs in Excel to store the query results.

For example, I want to query all the results that match criteria A, and write the result to an Excel tab named "A". The query result is stored in the panda data frame format.

My problem is, when I want to perform 4 different queries based on criteria "A", "B", "C", "D", the final Excel file only contains one tab, which corresponds to the last criteria in the list. It seems that all the previous tabs are over-written.

Here is sample code where I replace the SQL query part with a pre-set dataframe and the tab name is set to 0, 1, 2, 3 ... instead of the default Sheet1, Sheet2... in Excel.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import datetime



def GCF_Refresh(fileCreatePath, inputName):
    currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    currentDT = currentDT[0:10]
    loadExcelName = currentDT + '_' + inputName + '_Load_File'
    fileCreatePath = fileCreatePath +'\\' + loadExcelName+'.xlsx'
    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fileCreatePath)
    data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]

    # Create the pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileCreatePath, engine='xlsxwriter')

    for iCount in range(5):
        #worksheet = writer.sheets[str(iCount)]
        #worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Name')
        df['Name'].to_excel(fileCreatePath, sheet_name=str(iCount), startcol=0, startrow=1, header=None, index=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()

# Change the file path here to store on your local computer
GCF_Refresh("H:\\", "Bulk_Load")
```

My goal for this sample code is to have 5 tabs named, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and each tab has 'tom', 'nick' and 'juli' printed to it. Right now, I just have one tab (named 4), which is the last tab among all the tabs I expected.

Comment: It looks like you are saving, and therefore closing, the file in the loop. Therefore you overwrite it each time through the loop. Move that code outside the loop.

Comment: Hi,  jmcnamara, I moved those out and tried different variation with save and close, it still not seems to work. For example, when I move both (.save and .close) out of the loop, the file is now empty (only one empty sheet1). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in the code:

- The xlsx file is created using XlsxWriter directly and then overwritten by creating it Again in Pandas.
- The `to_excel()` method takes a reference to the `writer` object not the file path.
- The `save()` and `close()` are the same thing and shouldn't be in the
  loop.

Here is a simplified version of your code with these issues fixes:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

fileCreatePath = 'test.xlsx'
data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileCreatePath, engine='xlsxwriter')

for iCount in range(5):
    df['Name'].to_excel(writer, 
                        sheet_name=str(iCount), 
                        startcol=0, 
                        startrow=1, 
                        header=None, 
                        index=False)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

See [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) in the XlsxWriter docs for some details about getting Pandas and XlsxWriter working together.

Comment: Thus is the exact answer I was looking for. Very helpful! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else reading this, it's best to wrap this in a contextmanager

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

fileCreatePath = 'test.xlsx'
data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])
with pd.ExcelWriter(fileCreatePath, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for iCount in range(5):
        df['Name'].to_excel(writer, 
                            sheet_name=str(iCount), 
                            startcol=0, 
                            startrow=1, 
                            header=None, 
                            index=False)
```

By wrapping in a contextmanager you ensure that the resources, e.g excel is appropriately released